# I want to search any number inside the parentheses with some words in a string

Tags: python, python-re

I am taking input from user and trying to search that input keyword in a string..

```
import re

String_1 ='this year (2023) we will complete this project'

query=str(input('enter name: ' )) #suppose input is "this year (2023)"

raw_pattern = query.replace(' ', r'.*[\s\.\+\-_]')

regex = re.compile(raw_pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

cursor = regex.search(String_1)

print(cursor)
```

#but the output is None

Comment: what are you trying to do with `query.replace(' ', r'.*[\s\.\+\-_]')`?

Comment: Here I have given only one string but I have a database and there are lots of string in which _,+,. these are included

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the query first, the parentheses have a special meaning in regex (capturing group):

```
raw_pattern = re.escape(query).replace(' ', r'.*[\s\.\+\-_]')

# ...

print(cursor)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='this year (2023)'>
```

Comment: But what about query.replace(' ', r'.*[\s\.\+\-_]') this line? Is there any way so that it also works?

Comment: @Sameer no, because of the parentheses in `query`. My answer is the way to "*make it work*" ;)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `re.escape`? This is more generic and more efficient. This is my opinion, then you can do as you want ;)